# pass mouse wheel event from parent to child

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, mouseevent, smooth-scrolling

I have big parent div and narrow child div in the center of it.
When I scroll mouse wheel over child, it scrolls as it should,
but I want to be able to scroll that child element even if mouse is not on it, but somewhere on parent, and mouse wheel is scrolled.

I'm passing event from parent to child like this:

```
parent.addEventListener('mousewheel', parentMouseWheel);

function parentMouseWheel(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'parentId') { //to prevent double events when mouse is over child
   if (e.wheelDelta > 0) child.scrollTop = child.scrollTop - 120;
    else  child.scrollTop = child.scrollTop + 120;
  }
}
```

this works, but the problem is, there is no smooth scrolling like there is when I scroll mouse wheel over child (probably because of forcing/passing like this).
So, is there any other way to pass mouse wheel event to child, that will also trigger smooth scrolling?
I'm styling my extension options page, if that means anything...

Comment: I redid the tags: it's not extension-specific, and badly needs [tag:javascript] to reach the intended audience

Comment: @Xan I changed the whole concept. I had to put scrolling on parent, because smooth scrl. was never triggered (working) on child element.